# Parallel external supply to CR2450 coin battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, batteries

I have a temperature data logger which should be used within the time period of 1 year as according to the supplier the battery would be drained by this time.

The logger has a program stored inside a chip which I am unaware if volatile or non volatile and the supplier is not interested in providing more details.

I want to enhance battery life by providing an external power supply to the already present(and soldered) CR 2450. My idea is to stop the battery drain further as at current position battery is at 3.23 Volts which I believe is very good.

I cannot simply replace battery because battery is soldered to board which mean If I try to remove than it might lose the program stored probably.

My question is
Is it good idea to provide external supply of 3.3 Volts through a voltage regulator? Could it damage battery? If I do provide an external supply, what voltage and what amperage?

EDIT:
Processor in circuit is 432G2533
There is another chip 564Rk-K540, I google it and could not find purpose of it.

Comment: Yes, charging primary lithium cells can cause them to explode.

Comment: If you supply more voltage than present battery voltage, you will damage and/or explode the battery. People are not going to like it, but if you do manage to supply the same voltage as the battery (you won't), your external supply have lower impedance so most of the supply current will be taken from there and your battery will last longer. If you could modify the circuit, there are many good options for how to solve this. Otherwise, you are in a tight spot.

Comment: What is this product which has its 'program' stored in volatile memory, and has a design lifespan of less than a year?

Comment: Its simply a data logger that records data of temperature and transmit via radio frequency when device get signal to transmit data. Since data logger is not recording anything as push button is not pressed so I belive it would be in standby mode.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd cut the +3.2V trace leading from the battery, install a shotkkydiode bridging the gap, then simply connect the jack for supplying +3.3V external power past the diode.

After this, you will either:

1. Have a working device whose life can be extended fairly indefinitely using external power.
   -or-
2. Find out that there was stored program code in volatile memory, and know that more extreme (and potentially dangerous) measures will be needed if you want to continue to pursue this project.

Comment: Old answer, but to mitigate the second problem you can solder the diode _before_ you cut the trace. Of course, always observing that you are soldering in a powered circuit. Since it is battery operated, it should be ok.